# Find finds files that don't show up in ls

Tags: filesystem

I've run into the following situation.

`find` finds a partiuclar file:

```
$> find ./ -name "16_-_*.mp3"

 ... # other matches
./Music.mp3/Let's Wrestle/In The Court Of The Wrestling Let's/16_-_In The Court Of The Wrestling Let's.mp3
 ... # other matches
```

but it doesn't show up under `ls`

```
ls -a ./Music.mp3/Let\'s\ Wrestle/Let\'s\ Wrestle/
.  ..  01_Rain Ruins Revolution.mp3  02_I Am Fond of You.mp3  03_Codeine and Marshmallows.mp3  08_David You Know.mp3  cover.jpg
```

How do I fix this so that the file is back where it belongs?

Comment: *"How do I fix this so that the file is back where it belongs?"* `find` found the file `16_-_In The Court Of The Wrestling Let's.mp3` in `./Music.mp3/Let's Wrestle/In The Court Of The Wrestling Let's/`, but you're using `ls` to examine the contents of the different directory `./Music.mp3/Let\'s\ Wrestle/Let\'s\ Wrestle/`. If you look in the correct place, do you find it? If not, or if there is some other indication of a problem, then I recommend you **[edit]** this question with details. Based on the description given here, it is not clear why you believe the file is not in the correct place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` command is showing a file under:

```
./Music.mp3/Let's Wrestle/In The Court Of The Wrestling Let's/
```

while your `ls` command is listing files under:

```
./Music.mp3/Let's Wrestle/
```

Basically you're (1) directory too high with `ls`.

Comment: Rather than listing files under `./Music.mp3/Let's Wrestle/`, the OP's `ls` command is listing files under `./Music.mp3/Let\'s\ Wrestle/Let\'s\ Wrestle/`. So the directory listed by `ls` is at the same level as `./Music.mp3/Let's Wrestle/In The Court Of The Wrestling Let's/`, but still a different directory. The key point here--that the wrong directory's contents are being listed--is still correct.

Comment: @EliahKagan - good catch!